# Issue with .css when calling a div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What im trying to do is when the path is /prokennex/products have that page be set to certain css properties, padding set to 0 to be exact, but for some reason thats not working. Here is the function

```
(function() {
var path = window.location.pathname;
if (path == '/prokennex/products') {
  $('div.module-content').css('padding' , '0');
  alert('hello');
};
})();
```

the alert does go off but the css properties dont show, anything i could do to fix that? could it just be conflicting with its current css properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a document ready inside:

```
(function() {
   $(function(){ // add to this block
     var path = window.location.pathname;
     if (path == '/prokennex/products') {
       $('div.module-content').css('padding' , '0');
       alert('hello');
     };
   }); // add to this block
})();
```

---

Because of the structure of IIFE gets fired before dom is ready so this does not do any thing. jQuery methods like `.css()` needs the dom to get loaded first, when elements are ready jQuery gets executed.

Comment: that helped me out a lot, thank you for the explanation!